# Namespace in php under xampp

Tags: php, namespaces, directory, collision

I am working with php under xampp.

In my C:\xampp\htdocs\AppLib1\lib1.php

```
<?php
// application library 1 i.e. lib1.php
namespace AppLib1;

const MYCONST = 'AppLib1MYCONST';

function MyFunction() {
    return __FUNCTION__;
}

class MyClass {
    static function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
?>
```

and in my C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp.php

```
<?php
//myapp.php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
include_once ('lib1.php');

echo AppLib1MYCONST . "n";
echo AppLib1MyFunction() . "n";
echo AppLib1MyClass::WhoAmI() . "n";
?>
```

now when i am running myapp.php locally, I am getting  Fatal Error

**Warning**:  require_once(lib1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp.php** on line **3**

**Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib1.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp.php** on line **3**

Can some explain me how to use function, class, constant  from lib1.php

output should be:
AppLib1MYCONST
AppLib1MyFunction
AppLib1MyClass::WhoAmI

I  Know Name collision problems can be solved with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call it like this:

```
echo AppLib1\MYCONST . "n";
echo AppLib1\MyFunction() . "n";
echo AppLib1\MyClass::WhoAmI() . "n";
```